# How do I know product of two ints will exceed maximum int storage?

Tags: c++, function, c++17

I'm working on a function which takes in two ints like so: product(x, y) and returns the product of the two integers. Is there a way I could know that the product of these two ints will be a value larger than the value of INT32_MAX before I do the calculation so that I know there will be an error?

Comment: Maybe store both ints in a 64 bit integer type, do the product, and compare against INT32_MAX?

Comment: How is sum related to a product here?

Comment: You mean `x * y` or `x + y`?

Comment: I meant product sorry, as in x * y.

Comment: For `*`, and assuming a simple unsigned, it seems like if the sum of used bits (that is, position of MSB) per operand exceeds 32 then it would overflow. I might test that hypothesis on a few values.. as bits are power-of-two, and something something math about square roots.

Comment: For example, all in hex: FF*FF <= FFFF, 100*A0 > FFFF .. looking at the title, not practical implementations of detection-after :)

Comment: @user2864740 `0x7FFFFFFF * 0x00000000` will not overflow, so it's a little trickier.

Comment: Sum of bits (used through MSB) there is only 31 :D

Comment: @user2864740 two's complement is probably the same as unsigned 31 bit numbers, using absolute values

Comment: It's not clear this is a dup of the tagged question, which is asking about the SUM of 2 ints

Comment: A product of two integers is guaranteed to always fit the storage twice as big as its operands. So basically do what @cigien proposes, compute the product and store it in 64bit variable, compare agains INT32_MAX and if it fits, static_cast it to the smaller one and return, otherwise throw.

Comment: @doomista that sounds like an answer

Comment: both `+` and `*` have many duplicates: [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/995714), [How do I detect overflow while multiplying two 2's complement integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2713972/995714), [Catch and compute overflow during multiplication of two large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1815367/995714), [Which way to test for signed integer overflow on multiply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23166648/995714)...